# Pagination in SpringBatch ItemReader

Tags: java, spring-batch

I want to read data from an api endpoint using spring-batch .Is it possible for me to read the data in a paginated way.
Example :-

- First Request : Read 10 records process and write.
- Second Request : Read next 10 records process and write.

Comment: Does your API provide pagination?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Yes it does provide .

Comment: Follow spring-batch job implementation using the [chunks approach](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-tasklet-chunk#chunks).

Comment: Will this enable the api to be called in a paginated manner ? Say first i get 10 records and then next request it gets another 10 records ?

Answer (score 6):

Since your API already provides pagination, you can create a reader that extends `AbstractPagingItemReader` and implement the `doReadPage` method where you call the API to request a page of items (with a configurable size). If the endpoint is a REST endpoint, the reader can use a `RestTemplate` to make the call.

Comment: Can you elaborate it a bit . if you could help me with a code for reference.

Comment: I can't give an an example because you did not share how your API paginates replies. Please give an example of a paginated URL (like you would call it with `curl` or `httpie` or similar CLI tool) and I will try add an example.

Comment: He is an example I have used as reference.  It's something that @MahmoudBenHassine has worked on.  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/4.3.7/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.java

Comment: I am having similar requirement where I need to invoke rest API which gives 200 records at a time from a legacy system. Considering there will be millions of records to process and at a  time only 200 being received in API there will be lots of calls. I would like to understand spring batch is a way to go or we should have simple springboot service which keeps calling API until it stops giving result. In such scenario spring batch adds any additional benefit. As per my past experience I used spring batch only when I have to process millions of records at a time.